# OKhttp : SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I'm trying to figure out why sometimes I get this error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated:
>   ssl=0x60d46c90: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:1409443E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert inappropriate
>   fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x60d57f40:0x00000003)

[image]

**the code that makes this request:**

```
private <T> void send(final String url, final Map<String, String> args, 
    final RequestCallback<T> callback, final Parser<T> pParser, 
    final Context pContext, final HTTP_METHOD method, 
    final Map<String, String> headers, final BODY_TYPE bodyType) {

    final Request.Builder builder = getBuilder(url);
    populateHeaders(builder, headers);
    final RequestBody body = getBody(args, bodyType);

    if(method==HTTP_METHOD.POST) {
        builder.post(body);
    } else if(method==HTTP_METHOD.GET) {
        builder.get();
    } else if(method==HTTP_METHOD.PUT) {
        builder.put(body);
    } else if(method==HTTP_METHOD.PATCH) {
        builder.patch(body);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please specify correct method name!");
    }

    Request request = builder.build();
    debugRequest(request, whoCalledThisMethod());
    call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new StandardRequestCallback(pContext, callback, pParser));
}
```

I've found that if my app gets this exception, force-closing it, followed by re-launching it, can successfully complete the request... however, a short while later, it fails again with this SSL Exception.

What could be wrong ?

---

**UPDATE**

I made a very small test app that uses code from the okHttp recipes page https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes and I've repro'd the SSL Handshake Exception !!

```
06-27 13:59:08.068 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x60068d10: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
06-27 13:59:08.068 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err: error:1409443E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x6006e6b0:0x00000003)
06-27 13:59:08.078 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:568)
06-27 13:59:08.078 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188)
06-27 13:59:08.078 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
06-27 13:59:08.078 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108)
06-27 13:59:08.078 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
06-27 13:59:08.088 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x60068d10: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
06-27 13:59:08.098 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x5ff9aa20:0x00000003)
06-27 13:59:08.108 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:         ... 18 more
06-27 13:59:08.108 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x60068d10: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
06-27 13:59:08.108 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x5ff9aa20:0x00000003)
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:486)
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:         ... 17 more
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x60068d10: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err: error:1409443E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x6006e6b0:0x00000003)
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:486)
06-27 13:59:08.118 30006-32692/a.b.ssltestapp W/System.err:     ... 17 more
```

Comment: note: ANDROID 4.4.4

Comment: It is know bug in OkHttp: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1940

Comment: IMO, perhaps your network connection is poor sometimes which causes this issue. Moreover, have you tried with other Android API? This issue happened only in emulator or real device or both?

Comment: No, network connection is decent... but could be better. However, this problem shows up at multiple locations. Problem is reproducible on Device (I don't use emulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around - basically you create a new instance of the OkHttpClient ! See the code below ...

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button buttonStart;
    private Button buttonStop;
    private TextView textView;
    private Handler handler;

    private Integer mCount = 0;
    private Boolean mQuit;
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    final int DELAY_SUBSEQUENT_REQUEST = 5000;//5sec
    final String REQUEST_URL = "https://whatever.com/url/to/test";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();

        buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
        buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!mQuit) {
                    mCount++;
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(mCount));

                    // do the GET call here
                    RequestGet();
                }
            }
        };

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                triggerDelayedSslRequest(0);
                mQuit = false;
            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                mQuit = true;
                handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                mCount = 0;
            }
        });
    }

    private void triggerDelayedSslRequest(int delay)
    {
        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, delay);
    }

    private void RequestGet()
    {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(REQUEST_URL)
                .build();

        // NOTE: onFailure and onResponse are not on the main thread
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
                // the SSL error is trapped here
                e.printStackTrace();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(e.getMessage());
                        buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });

                // Crazy "fix" for SSLException
                if(e instanceof SSLException) {
                    client = new OkHttpClient();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText("Error Response: "+response.toString());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    System.out.println(response.body().string());
                }

                // schedule the next GET request
                triggerDelayedSslRequest(DELAY_SUBSEQUENT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="a.b.ssltestapp.ActivityMain">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/buttonstart"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/buttonstop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonstart"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Press START to test SSL"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonstop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

However, this fix is highly inconvenient.

**To summarize the fix:**

- Launch the app and let it sit for maybe 20 minutes (maybe at this point make your wifi turn off and back on? I'm sure at work, that's what happens)
- Now press the START button in the app
- Observe the SSL Handshake Exception (at this point a new OkHttpClient instance is created).
- Press the START button again
- Observe that GET requests are now successful.

*What is it about creating a new OkHttpClient object that makes the SSL Handshake work again ?*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: No, nothing yet :(

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution but provides some network debugging in case it relates to the issue mentioned above.

If it is the problem with the network interface mentioned in issue 1940 above then you can workaround that issue by implementing the Dns interface, and also the socketFactory. It *could* be you get back two DNS records and one works for you and the other doesn't, and it changes after a restart.

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/network/DnsSelector.java

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/network/InterfaceSocketFactory.java

Try confirming by adding debugging looking at the results of

`Dns.SYSTEM.lookup(hostname)`

`NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address)`

`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`

---

**UPDATE**

Code within the Callback.OnFailure to debug this problem :

```
@Override
public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {
    if (call.isCanceled()) {
        SLog.w(TAG, "onFailure: Canceled");
        return;
    }

    if(e instanceof SSLException){

        try {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Checking DNS hosts ... ");
            List<InetAddress> list = Dns.SYSTEM.lookup(call.request().url().host());
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Number of Entries: "+list.size());
            for (InetAddress address : list) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), address.toString());
            }
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "End of Checking DNS hosts");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Checking Network Interfaces ... ");
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            ArrayList<NetworkInterface> list = Collections.list(interfaces);
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Number of Entries: "+list.size());
            for(NetworkInterface netintface : list) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), netintface.toString());
                List<InterfaceAddress> listaddresses = netintface.getInterfaceAddresses();
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "   Number of Interface Addresses: "+listaddresses.size());
                for (InterfaceAddress infcaddress : listaddresses) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "   > InterfaceAddress : "+infcaddress.toString());
                }
            }
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "End of Checking Network Interfaces");
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

DEBUG OUTPUT from code above

```
06-21 11:43:19.495 12890-12890/com.app.stg D/[StandardRequest]: ->
                                                                   ------------- Request -------------
                                                                   ********** METHOD sendRequest() **********
                                                                   GET
                                                                   -----------------------------------
06-21 11:43:24.330 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: Checking DNS hosts ... 
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: Number of Entries: 8
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.145
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.20
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.185
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.84
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.249
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.52
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.159
06-21 11:43:24.450 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: arc.stg.issa.sainsburys.co.uk/52.85.69.246
06-21 11:43:24.460 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: End of Checking DNS hosts
06-21 11:43:24.460 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: Checking Network Interfaces ... 
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: Number of Entries: 4
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: [lo][1][/::1%1%1][/127.0.0.1]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    Number of Interface Addresses: 2
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    > InterfaceAddress : /::1%1%1/128 [null]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    > InterfaceAddress : /127.0.0.1/8 [null]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: [sit0][2]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    Number of Interface Addresses: 0
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: [wlan0][4][/fe80::4283:deff:fe94:b0ff%wlan0%4][/172.24.90.253]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    Number of Interface Addresses: 2
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    > InterfaceAddress : /fe80::4283:deff:fe94:b0ff%wlan0%4/64 [null]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    > InterfaceAddress : /172.24.90.253/19 [/172.24.95.255]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: [ip6tnl0][3]
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback:    Number of Interface Addresses: 0
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-21401/com.app.stg D/StandardRequestCallback: End of Checking Network Interfaces
06-21 11:43:24.480 12890-12890/com.app.stg D/JS-[LauncherActivity]: ErrorReport{type='SSLHandshakeException'}
```

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks for the suggestions - I'll get those 3 API calls implemented to get you the results when the SSL Handshake exception happens.

Comment: please see the edits I placed in your post. You can see that all the data is collected as soon as the SSLexception is trapped. It looks like there's still an active wifi connection. Note: at this point, the app is unable to send requests until it's restarted

Comment: I suspect this might be a dead end. You are getting back multiple routes, so OkHttp should be able to try each one in turn provided you haven't disabled retryOnConnectionFailure.

You have an ipv4 and ipv6 interface, maybe one of those is broken for you, but I can't see why. 

You could try comparing it to when things are working, but honestly, I don't know why it doesn't try each route in turn after a failure and fix itself without restart.  sorry.

Comment: I've tried `builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);` and `builder.followSslRedirects(true);` but no difference. The GET requests work at the start of app launch and then a few minutes later fail with the SSL Handshake Exception. Is it possible to track down the reason of the handshake exception ? I've tried Certificate pinning, but that yields the exact same failure.

Comment: I've logged the networking information when a GET request is successful and everything looks exactly the same, other than the order of the 8 DNS hosts.

Comment: Read through this and see if it helps

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1582

It seems related to the error you are getting "tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback", but I'm out of my depth here.